# How to Lazy load webView in react native?

Tags: react-native, android-webview, youtube-iframe-api, youtubeplayer, react-lazy-load

> I have Implemented using React.lazy and Suspense in react-native but it seems it does not working with react-native.

> I had followed [This Youtube Video](https://youtu.be/ZOpf_ueF65A/)

> Basicaly I want to embed Youtube Player in react native app using [react-native-youtube-iframe](https://github.com/LonelyCpp/react-native-youtube-iframe) which uses webviw behind the scenes. but it makes the screen slow and feels like buggy.

> I just want to lazy load this.

Answer (score 0):

`React.lazy` is about code-splitting which is not actual if you are using React Native and Hermes. Otherwise, if you don't use Hermes you can try Ram Bundle https://reactnative.dev/docs/ram-bundles-inline-requires.

Comment: Gone through the blog but did't understand anything, can you explains how it answers the Question sir

Comment: @UdbhavVikramSingh do you use Hermes JS engine?